# disable an element in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react Js and i wanna set disable some of element according to the conditions

I have three element in my form one select and two input

according to selected item one of input must be disable

this is my component code:

```js
class AddUser extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
user: {
}

};

}

render() {
    if (this.props.user) {
        this.state.user= this.props.user;
    }    

return (

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="control-label">type<span className="symbol required"></span></label>
            <select className="form-control" name="CompanyMeetingType" value={this.state.user.type>
                <option value="1"> type1</option>
                <option value="2">type2</option>
                <option value="3">both</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="control-label">type1(%)<span className="symbol required"></span></label>
            <input required type="text" name="type1" className="form-control" disabled={this.state.user.type ==2} />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="control-label">type1(%)<span className="symbol required"></span></label>
            <input required type="text" name="type2" className="form-control" disabled={this.state.user.type ==1} />
        </div>
)

}
```

when I'm changing the selected item disable work correctly but when I'm filing select element in edit mode disable not work

Comment: you dont have any onChange handlers...

Comment: i added it but disable doesn't work Still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Application extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: '1'
    }
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
}
handleSelect(e) {
    console.log('enter');
    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value
    })
}
render() {
    console.log(this.state.value)
    return ( 
      <div >
        <select value = { this.state.value} onChange = {this.handleSelect} >
         <option value = "" >select value </option>
         <option value = "1" >value 1 </option>
         <option value = "2" >value 2 </option>
         <option value = "3" >both </option>
         </select> 
         <br / >
        <hr / >
        <input type = "text" disabled = {this.state.value == 1 || this.state.value == 3 }/>
        < br / > < br / >
        < input type = "text" disabled = { this.state.value == 2 || this.state.value == 3 }/> 
      < /div>
     );
    }
  }
React.render( < Application / > , document.getElementById('app'))
```

The only thing that you are missing is handleSelect function which handles the event of select value and sets state. it works perfectly as you want. and if you want to pre default disable any input tag then just pass that value in the state so when component will render that tag will be disabled.

Comment: thank you for your answer but when I'm setting initialize value for select disable not work for example when in render function I'm setting 1 for value I expect It make first input disable but it doesn't work correctly

Comment: You have to add event listener onChange in select tag and call a function which will call everytime you select any option value and where you define function pass e by which we can get the value whatsoever is selected. As a developer view add some console.log what value you are getting. Like add a console.log just after your function defines and add console.log just after render and print your selected type so that you will know on changing any option value is function calling or not and the value is changing or not.

Comment: there are some error in your code check how i define constructor and you need to add close curly brace for constructor because constructor and render are different function, render can not be inside constructor function, and in constructor function you this.state = {user: {} } is wrong approach you should go with this.state : { user: { } }

Comment: You have so many syntax error, there is one parent tag in jsx you don't have, <select className="form-control" name="CompanyMeetingType" value={this.state.user.type> in this line you are missing closing curly brace.

Comment: if you want to disable first input on render (without selecting any option then just pass value 1 in state )

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `onChange` handlers. Try:

```
<select 
  className="form-control" 
  name="CompanyMeetingType" 
  value={this.state.user.type} 
  onChange={(e) => this.setState({ user: { type: e.target.value } })}>
   <option value="1"> type1</option>
   <option value="2">type2</option>
   <option value="3">both</option>
</select>
```